# How can i extract a text from a book in a webpage?

Tags: python, web-scraping

how can I extract the text of this book as it is from the webpage and the text should include it's extra white spaces and punctuation marks
(https://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/bws.aspx)

I wrote this code

```
import requests
import string
import re
result=requests.get('https://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/bws.aspx')
src=result.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(src,'lxml')
oldbook=soup.find("div",{"align":"justify"})
book=oldbook.text.replace('s%_'," ")
```

but the output contains \n\n\n\n instead of extra white spaces and \r

**part from the output:**

'\n\n\n\n\n\n“I have an exposition of sleep come upon me.”\n—Shakespeare.\n\n\n\n\n\n\r\n\r\nI have frequently wondered if the majority of mankind ever pause to reflect upon the occasionally\r\ntitanic significance of dreams, and of the obscure world to which they belong.

**How can I solve this?**

Comment: ``book.strip()`` ??

Answer (score 0):

To clean the text, you can use `.get_text()` with `strip=True` and `separator='\n'`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get(
    "https://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/bws.aspx"
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, "lxml")

oldbook = soup.find("div", {"align": "justify"})
print(oldbook.get_text(strip=True, separator="\n"))
```

Prints:

```
“I have an exposition of sleep come upon me.”
—Shakespeare.
I have frequently wondered if the majority of mankind ever pause to reflect upon the occasionally
titanic significance of dreams, and of the obscure world to which they belong. Whilst the greater
number of our nocturnal visions are perhaps no more than faint and fantastic reflections of
our waking experiences—Freud to the contrary with his puerile symbolism—there are

...
```

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is present because it's present in the HTML. (Line-breaks).

A brower styles pages separately, not necessarily by "extra white spaces".
There are actually no "extra whitespcaes" present in the text in the sentence you mentioned, instead it's enclosed in a separate HTML tag and styled using CSS.

You can try to identify these special tags and extract text from them separately, and get rid of more than one contiguous whitespace blocks using regex.